# Sat4j Remote Control window doesn't open

Tags: sat4j

## What happens:

I execute the following command.

```
java -jar sat4j-sat.jar -remote
```

No window opens, and I get a console output same as without the -remote flag, which begins:

```
c SAT4J: a SATisfiability library for Java (c) 2004-2013 Artois (...)
c This is free software under the dual EPL/GNU LGPL licenses.
c See www.sat4j.org for details.
c version 2.3.4.v20130419
c java.runtime.name OpenJDK Runtime Environment
c java.vm.name      OpenJDK Client VM
c java.vm.version   24.65-b04
c java.vm.vendor    Oracle Corporation
c sun.arch.data.model   32
c java.version      1.7.0_65
c os.name       Linux
c os.version        3.2.0-4-686-pae
(...)
```

## What is expected:

From readme.txt:

> To run sat4j with on the fly configuration:
>
> ```
> java -jar sat4j-sat.jar -remote
> ```
>
> These instructions should open a java window named Remote Control. We
>   assume that the 1.5 version of the java command is in your path. If
>   it isn’t, then you should either specify the complete path to the java
>   command or update your PATH environment variable as described in the
>   installation instructions for the Java 2 SDK.

## Other details

I have tried multiple versions of the library, up to 2.3.4.

My system is Debian 7 with Gnome 2.

My default Java installation is OpenJDK 1.7.0_65.

My secondary Java installation is Oracle Java 1.8.0_45 (with the same issue).

Gnuplot 4.6 is installed.

My first machine has a 32 bit dual core CPU with 2GB of RAM.

My second machine has a 64 bit quad core CPU with 8GB of RAM with nearly identical software.

## Question

Has anyone used SAT4J's remote control feature? What is the problem with my method?

## Update

On another machine (64 bit Debian 7) the window opens. After start dat files are created, but plotting does not start.

## Update 2

I ran the generated `instance.dimacs-gnuplot.gnuplot` file manually from a gnuplot terminal, and I got the message `unknown or ambiguous terminal type` for the `x11` type. I installed the `gnuplot-x11` package, and now it works on the workplace machine: I can see the diagrams (wow!). Unfortunately on my home machines the Remote Control window still doesn't open.

Answer (score 1):

The `-remote` parameter is used to display the remote control, i.e. to setup the various parameters of the solver.

If you want to always monitor what the solver is doing, you need to use in conjunction the `-r` parameter.

So the complete command line should be:

```
java -jar sat4j-sat.jar -r -remote file.cnf
```

You can get a fresh snapshot of Sat4j Sat on our continuous integration server:
http://bamboo.ow2.org/browse/SAT4J-DEF2-41/artifact/JOB1/nightly_build/

This might solve the issue you met with the 2.3.4 release.

Cheers,

Daniel

Comment: Thanks for the great link. Unfortunately, this new jar file also does not open the Remote Control window. I have tried it with different Debian 7 machines.

Comment: Sorry, the sat4j-sat package was missing a required lib file. Could you try exactly that version: http://bamboo.ow2.org/artifact/SAT4J-DEF2/JOB1/build-45/nightly_build/sat4j-sat4j-sat-v20150718.zip

Comment: BTW, could you provide us the version of Java you are running?
`java --version`

Comment: I have upgraded my question with new informations including Java version. I have no luck with the new jar file (same results occur with it). I will try with another Java distribution.

Comment: On my machine at work opens the Remote Control window with the 20150718 version. But there is no solver int the combo, and plotting does not start (even with custom solver). I tried it with multiple versions of Java, multiple desktop environments and other varied settings. Okay, in theory, what is the full scenario to visualize solving of a given dimacs file?

Comment: New info: If I press the start button, then a NullPointerException throws: **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.sat4j.sat.DetailedCommandPanel.launchSolverWithConfigs(DetailedCommandPanel.java:897)**

Comment: David, the build from July 13 was missing a required library. I created a new one yesterday: http://bamboo.ow2.org/artifact/SAT4J-DEF2/JOB1/build-45/nightly_build/sat4j-sat4j-sat-v20150718.zip

That build works fine for me.

The remote indeed require that you have either gunplay installed or use a full java visualizer. By default, you get the latter.